# Modeling a form with an Auto-Suggest Lookup in Backbone.js

Tags: ajax, backbone.js

I have report UI with a small form at top where the user looks up a person by name using an Auto-Suggest textbox, and I set a hidden ID field when they select one.  They then enter a start and end date, and hit submit to load a report below.  The report data is fetched using the Person's ID, and the date range as a Backbone route. I can also show the person's name in the report header since I have it from the Auto-Suggest lookup.

The problem is, if someone bookmarks a report (a nice feature to have), I'd like to repopulate the form (which shows the person's name) and the report header.

So, currently I have one route ('id/startdate/to/enddate') that sometimes is triggered by an already populated form model, and sometimes is triggered by a bookmark/refresh and needs to repopulate the form model from route data and server-side data.

How would you model this? I was going to have a model bound to the form:

```
{ id: 234, name: 'Bill', startDate: '1/1/2011', endDate: '1/1/2012' }
```

But I am struggling with this idea of sometimes needing to fetch the name and populate the form, and sometimes already having a populated form (and name). Feels like there should be a better design for my Backbone views/models/routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate your Model from the router by triggering a message with the name, startDate etc parameters that the Model will listen to.

The same thing can be done in the View that sets the data on the Model. So, regardless of where you get the information from (View, Router), your Model would correctly hold the state.

Then your Form View could listen on changes to its Model, re-rendering itself with pre-filled information on Model change.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Radek - thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up modeling the Auto-Suggest UI as it's own model, which helped clear some things up.  Not sure it's the cleanest in can be, but it works and isn't too bad.  Still considering refactoring options.